# How can I getObjectId via onItemClick on ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform

I want use click listener to get ObjectId from parse.com，but the have something wrong I cant figure out. After Click item, getobjectId by click, and updating the new click Number to Parse.com

```
  int ClickNum = (Integer) CN.get("ClickNumber");
```

Here have issues... Can you help me...
Toast and Log.d also not working here..
Thanks for your time

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into an ArrayAdapter
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                    R.layout.listview_item);
            int i=0;
            ArrayList<String>  GirlList= new ArrayList<String>();

            String[] mStringArray ;

            // Retrieve object "name" from Parse.com database
            for (ParseObject AVgirl : ob) {
                i++;

                adapter.add(i+"."+(String) AVgirl.get("GirlName"));

//              Log.d("123",(String) AVgirl.get("GirlName"));
            //GirlList.add((String) AVgirl.get("GirlName"));
            }


            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            // Capture button clicks on ListView items
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


                String Queen = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


                ParseObject CN = new ParseObject(Queen);

                int ClickNum = (Integer) CN.get("ClickNumber");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.class,Queen,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                ClickNum++;
                CN.put("ClickNumber", ClickNum);

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        SingleItemView.class);
                // Pass data "name" followed by the position
                i.putExtra("name", ob.get(position).getString("GirlName")
                        .toString());

                // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Sorry, I cant upload here
logcat: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6QnZ.png

updating, Yes, I figure out something during past 6 hour, and It's  the code right now

```
                // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SingleItemView.class);
                // Pass data "name" followed by the position
                i.putExtra("name", ob.get(position).getString("GirlName")
                        .toString());

                String girlname1 = "b";
                Intent girlname = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleItemView.class); 
                girlname.putExtra(girlname1, ob.get(position).getString("GirlName")
                        .toString());

                String ItemobjectId = "a";
                Intent Plus1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SingleItemView.class); 
                Plus1.putExtra(ItemobjectId, ob.get(position).getString("ObjectId")
                        .toString());

                System.out.println("點擊的是"+girlname1+"ObjectId ="+Plus1);


                ParseObject CN = new ParseObject("AVGirlList");
                String PlusAdd =  Plus1.toString();

                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("AVGirlList");
                query.getInBackground(PlusAdd, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                     int s = object.getInt("ClickNumber");
                     System.out.println(s);
                     s = s+1;
                     object.put("ClickNumber",  s);
                     object.saveInBackground();

                    } else {

                    }
                  }
                });

                // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

and log cat is here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRHaT.png
   //216 line:

```
Plus1.putExtra(ItemobjectId, ob.get(position).getString("ObjectId").toString());
```

It seem I cant use this method like that.
Please Help, Thanks

Comment: Did there get logged any errors in logcat?

Comment: please post your logcat here